# Export LibreOffice Colour Scheme

Tags: libreoffice

I changed the colour scheme in LibreOffice (Tools → Options → Appearance) and defined my own colour scheme.
I would like to know where (in which file or database) this new colour scheme was saved to reuse it on other computers or if there is a way to export the new colour scheme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the Windows version of LibreOffice it is saved in the following file:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Application Data\LibreOffice\4\user\registrymodifications.xcu
```

or

```
C:\Users\<username>\Application Data\LibreOffice\4\user\registrymodifications.xcu
```

On Linux systems it is:

```
/home/<username>/.config/libreoffice/4/user/registrymodifications.xcu
```

---

In case you wonder how I found it:

- I saved a color scheme with a (probably) unique name like `sch21w45`
- I ran a Notepad++ search for `sch21w45` in multiple files in the `%APPDATA%\Libreoffice\4` directory
- all search results pointed to `registrymodifications.xcu`

Comment: The path for linux is correct, too.

Comment: Thanks, the new colour scheme is well in the `registrymodifications.xcu` file. But this file contains a lot of data, does anyone know how to export only the colour scheme from a computer to another ?

Comment: Libre Office hasn't yet got this covered I think.